# Stucked while testing for a file transfer speed of 10 TB of file from server1 to server 2

Tags: filesystems, mount, scp, aws

I'm doing a testing of transferring 10 TB of files from one server to other server via AWS.

I have mounted the file system:

```
lsblk
file -s /dev/sdb
mkfs -t xfs /dev/sdb
mkdir /data
mount /dev/sdb /data
cd /data
```

Created a 10 TB file of data using the following command:

```
dd if=/dev/nvme1n1 of=test10t.img bs=1 count=0 seek=10T
```

(Is this correct or any other good options to download sample files of 10 TB size)

the `ls -laSh` shows as 10 TB of file got downloaded. However, `df -h` shows as:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        464M     0  464M   0% /dev
tmpfs           472M     0  472M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           472M  596K  472M   1% /run
tmpfs           472M     0  472M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1  8.0G  8.0G   16K 100% /
tmpfs            95M     0   95M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/nvme1n1     11T   79G   11T   1% /data
tmpfs            95M     0   95M   0% /run/user/0
```

10 TB of size not utilized fully. Can anyone explain on this please?

Also, while doing SCP from one server to other one using the command:

```
scp -i <password-of-second-server> <10TB file> ec2-user@<ip-address of other server>:~
```

it showing as transferring files. But the transfer didn't complete yet because of the larger file size and becoming slow once it crosses 100GB. I'm transferring from server1 to server2. In the server1 cli, it 's showing as in progresswith around 25 GB/hour average progress.
Can anyone guide and correct if this is the right way that help to complete my requirement?

Comment: `dd` doesn't download anything. You've shown us that you created a sparse file that's 20TB is size but using very much less storage.

Comment: Could you share the exact command that downloads 10 TB dummy data. I have tried from fallocate, but got some errors.

Comment: `fallocate` doesn't download anything either. Your `dd` and any use of `fallocate` will create a sparse file that looks like it's 10TB but takes up very little storage. Do you understand what "sparse" means?

Comment: You seem to be trying to use `scp` to copy (to download) the data file. But your description of even that is suspect. Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/729855/edit) to explain which parts you have actually succeeded with, and which part(s) you are having problems with. Since you are dealing with two servers, please make it quite clear which set of instructions applies to which server (source or destination)

Comment: yes. I understood that as it just creating a file which can accommodate the 10 TB of size. If i'm transferring this file to the other server, will the whole file will get transferred. If my requirement is to test 10 TB data transfer from server 1 to server 2, shouldn't I fill some some data of that size inside the file? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Please [**edit your question**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/729855/edit) to clarify issues, so that it's easy for everyone to follow your question. Don't respond here in the comments.

Comment: "_25 GB/hour_" is very approximately 55 Mb/s. What's your expected link speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `scp`... Maybe the cause of the badness could be that the remote host isn't seeing activity on the connection and is timing out.

Confirm the following entries in `sshd_config` on the remote host:

```
ClientAliveInterval 250
ClientAliveCountMax 16
```

Another thing you could do is to split the 10TB file up using the `shar` command. Then `scp` each shar file.